# Cat Leg amputation - Will fur grow back?

Tags: cats, grooming

My cat got his leg amputated the other day. Will fur grow back where the leg was? or will he just have a bald spot?

Answer (score 4):

In general - when a pet's limb is amputated, the vet tends to stitch a flap of skin over it to cover it up. Generally - longer term it'll grow back. In the short term, probably worth checking with your vet if its desirable and how you're expected to maintain the stump